# how to fetch value at particular location and also to set value in a LIst of integer in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

code i m trying is :-

```
$sumList1= New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[int]
$sumList1.Add(1)
$sumList1.Add(2)
$sumList1.Add(3)
$sumList1.Add(4)

$i = $sumList1.Items[1];
write-host $i
```

please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo, it is `Item()`, not `Items[]`: `$sumList1.Item(1)`

Or use normal index access: `$i = $sumList1[1]`

To change the value of an existing item use `$sumList1[1] = 5`, if you want to add an element use the `Add` method as in your sample code.

Comment: how to use it ?? while running it.It showing this error                                                                                                 ""Cannot index into a null array.
At D:\Powercel\testingsample.ps1:8 char:22
+ $i = $sumList1.Items[ <<<< $in];
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (1:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray""

Comment: Just replace your line `$i = $sumList1.Items[1]` with the code from my answer.

Comment: Thanks man i got this .....it working fine.....Could u please tell me how to set value also in it ?